# time using gap between while(scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF) and while(scanf("%d",&n) && n!=EOF)

Tags: c, scanf, eof

My question is not about algorithm, but something confusing about C programming language.
I met a problem as below:

**Problem description**

N! (N factorial) can be quite irritating and difficult to compute for large values of N. So instead of calculating N!, I want to know how many digits are in it. (Remember that N! = N * (N - 1) * (N - 2) * ... * 2 * 1)

**Input**

Each line of the input will have a single integer N on it 0 < N < 1000000 (1 million). Input is terminated by end of file.

**Output**

For each value of N, print out how many digits are in N!.

My code is like that:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
    int n ;
    while(scanf("%d",&n)&&n!=EOF)//1
    //while(scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF)//2
    {
        int result=1;
        int i;
        double temp = 1;
        for(i=n;i>0;i--)
        {
            temp*=i;
            while((temp/10)>1)
            {
                result++;
                temp=temp/10;
            }           
        }
        printf("%d\n",result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I used `while(scanf("%d",&n) && n!=EOF)`, the Online judge I was using showed that `Time Limit Exceeded`,when I changed it to `while(scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF)`, every thing goes well.I think `n!=EOF` may take too much time, So what is the essence of `EOF` ?

Comment: EOF is defined as -1 I.E. 0xFFFFFFFF for a 32 bit system.  However, there are a couple of problems with the call to the scanf function: 1) the code should always check the returned value from scanf to assure the input/conversion was successful 2) the returned value from scanf will NEVER by EOF,  it will be 0 or greater.

Comment: the count for the number of digits is awkward and not in the right location.  The 'count for the number of digits' only needs to be performed for the final value of N!.  Note: N! very quickly exceeds the ability of a 'int' to hold.  Suggest using 'long long int' (64bits) (or perhaps the 'bignum' functions).

Comment: @user3629249 1) `EOF` is not defined as `-1`.  It certainly is always a negative `int` constant. 2) The possible return value of `scanf("%d",&n)` are `0`, `1` or `EOF`.

Comment: Note: Code could run faster (and more accurately) with something like `for(i=n;i>0;i--) { temp *= i; while(temp >= 1.0e31) { result += 31; temp /= 1.0e31; } }  while(temp >= 10.0) { result++; temp /= 10.0;}  printf("%d\n",result);`.  31 chosen as `DBL_MAX` is at _least_ `1.0e31 * 1,000,000`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not the time of the 2 sentences, is that they have different meaning

The next one compares the value read by scanf with EOF, this is an error, scanf will not load any value in n if it reaches end of file:

```
while(scanf("%d",&n) && n!=EOF)
```

This one is the correct way to detect end of file:

```
while(scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF)
```

Generally EOF == -1, as the input in the judge doesn't contains -1 your program loops indefinitely.

As stated in the comments checking how many conversions scanf did is better in general, as it checks if the input is more or less valid(*). Given you asked 1 conversion in the format string ("%d") you can check if scanf returns 1:

```
while(scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
```

(*) It may fail to verify some cases if you have to follow a strict format (for example if the number is required to be followed by exaclty one \n), it would be even better do the conversions with strtol, checking that strtol consumes the complete line.

As this particular problem is from a programming contest using an online judge the input is well formed and such tests are usually not necessary.

Comment: Note that detecting EOF won't help if the input is malformed and contains, say, a letter or stray punctuation such as `'='` in the input.  The correct test is `while (scanf("%s", &n) == 1)` which continues while `scanf()` successfully converts the input to an `int` value.  Of the two, though, the `scanf(…) != EOF` is more nearly correct where the input is reasonably under control, as in Online Judge operations.

Answer (score 3):

Neither condition is proper one to use (but the one with `scanf("%d", &n) != EOF` is the better one to use).

The loop should be written as:

```
while (scanf("%d",&n) == 1)
```

because you're asking `scanf` to convert 1 value, and the return value from `scanf` is the number of items successfully converted.

Answer (score 0):

```
I would strongly suggest using the following code rather than 
the illmannered scanf() function:

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n ;            // user input after conversion
    long long int result=0;     // maybe use uint64_t
    char inArray[100] = {'\0'}; // user input array
    int i;                      // loop counter
    int digitCount = 0;         // number of digits to display factorial value

    printf("\nwhen enter a number\n"); 
    printf(" then pgm will output factorial for that number\n");
    printf(" then number of digits in factorial value\n");

    printf("\n\nPlease enter first number: (or <ctrl-z> to exit)");
    while( NULL != fgets( inArray, sizeof(inArray), stdin )
    {
        n = (unsigned)atoi( inArray );
        if( 0 == n )      {result = 0;}
        else if( 1 == n ) {result = 1;}
        else if( 2 == n ) {result = 2;}
        else
        {
            result = n;
            for(i=(n-1);i>1;i--)
            {
                result *= i;
            } // end calculate factorial
        } // end if

        printf("factorial value: %lld\n",result);

        // setup work area usage
        memset( inArray, 0x00, sizeof(inArray) );
        sprintf( inArray, "%lld", result );

        // calculate and display number of digits
        digitCount = strlen(inArray);
        printf("digit count: %d\n", digitCount );

        // clear work area and prompt for next input from user
        memset( inArray, 0x00, sizeof(inArray) );
        printf("\n\nPlease enter next number: (or <ctrl-z> to exit)");
    } // end while

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```